# How do I get a div class to set its own width out of the div id's inheritance on Chrome?

Tags: html, css

I am not getting the desired results when I try to get a div class to set its own width on chrome, it works on edge, and w3.

Website: kuzcos.com/reviews

Here is the code I have:

How would I fix this?

Thanks.

```css
html {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  color: #ff3427;
  font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Cambria", serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  color: #ff3427;
  font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Cambria", serif;
  margin: auto;
}

div#content {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #06C;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  color: #ff3427;
  font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Cambria", serif;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 700px;
}

div.reviewContent {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 2px solid #C0C0C0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  color: #ff3427;
  display: block;
  font-family: "Book Antiqua", "Cambria", serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="reviewContent">
    test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What result are you getting?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by: "get a div class to set its own width"

Comment: **1.** Ref: *"I am not getting the desired results"*. How are we supposed to know which are the desired results? **2.** What exactly do you mean by *"it works on w3"*?

Comment: the results I am getting is the child reviewContent div is remaining the exact same size as the parent content div. instead of setting it's own width as I specify. It works on the Edge Browser as well as within the W3Schools client just not on Chrome.

Comment: it works fine in my chrome. link or snippet here. actually no reason why it should not as it is

Comment: The code snippet shows it correct with two borders, but when I go to my webpage on Chrome it just shows one border without processing it. It seems to be inheriting the class content instead of reviewContent. Safari on iOS runs it perfectly as well. Just seems to be Chrome.

Comment: I opened it on another PC with Chrome and it seems to work fine there...I don't know what's stopping it from working on the Chrome on my developer PC but it's on my end...sorry.